# linked linked insertion function

Tags: c, linked-list

Hello I am trying to create n number of lists. Each list is ordered linked list with a new instance. However, I also need a combined ordered linked list. Following is the code for the same. When it comes to each independent list I do not have any problems. However, when I am trying to insert every node into a globally declared linked list nodes, I am getting error(The input crashes with iteration of one node value.) Please have a look at the function and call highlighted to make things clear where I am exactly getting the error. Please make a note of global declarations. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node{
    int number;
    struct node*next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

NODE*createlist(int),*rel_strt,*new_entry[100];
NODE *start1=NULL,*rear1,*m1,*temp11;
NODE *insert_in_end(NODE*node1);

int i,num,n2,j,v,u;

int main() {   
    v=0;u=0;
    printf("\n Enter the number of lists:");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++) {
        printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ",j+1);
       scanf("%d",&num);
       new_entry[v]=createlist(num);
       display(new_entry[v]);
        v++;
    }
    printf("\nThe final List is:");
    display(start1);
    return 0;
}

NODE*insert_in_end(NODE *node11) {  //problem in this function

    int inf1=node11->number;

    if(start1==NULL) {
        start1=rear1=node11;
    } else {   
        m1=start1;
        if(m1->number>inf1) {
            node11->next=m1;
            start1=node11;
        } else {
           while(m1->next) {
                if(m1->next->number < inf1)
                    m1=m1->next;
                else
                    break;
            }
            temp11=m1->next;
            m1->next=node11;
            node11->next=temp11;
        }
    }
    return start1;
}

void display(NODE*nodex) {
    while(nodex!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ->",nodex->number);
        nodex=nodex->next;
    }
}

NODE *createlist(int n1) {

    NODE *node1,*start,*rear,*m,*temp1;
    start=NULL;

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        node1=(NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        int inf;
        printf("Enter node value %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&inf);
        node1->number=inf;
        node1->next=NULL;
        insert_in_end(node1);  // error during second fuction call check function definition

        if(start==NULL) {
            start=rear=node1;
        } else {
            m=start;
            if(m->number>inf) {
                node1->next=m;
                start=node1;
            } else {
                while(m->next) {
                    if(m->next->number < inf)
                        m=m->next;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                temp1=m->next;
                m->next=node1;
                node1->next=temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You are apparently trying to insert the node in two lists at the same time. One is the short list and the other the global list. This can't be done because the node has only one successor. The successor in both lists are different. You have to create a copy of the node so that each list has its own copies.

Comment: So can you please tell me how to do it. I tried creating another variable pointer nx1 of type NODE and tried copying node1 value to it before calling the function and using nx1 as arguement.

Comment: That seams the right way. Note that your first have to malloc a new node to hold the copy. Then you copy the node fields. When done you insert the node copy in the global list.

Comment: You need only one function to insert a number in an ordered linked list. You can then use the same function for the short lists and the global list. This function would need a pointer on the first element of the linked list and the number to insert. Why do you have a rear pointer ? Was this requested ? It's not needed.

Comment: @chmike can you give me an example of insert node function relevant to my case. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a function insertValue that would make it much more convenient for you. It will also make your code much more readable. 
The function is below and you should see that it is very close to what you have.

```
// Returns the new start of the list after inserting value in increasing order
Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value)
{
   Node *newNode, *m;
   newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   newNode->number = value;   // added this
   newNode->next = NULL;      // added this
   if(list == NULL)
       return newNode;
   if(value < list->number)
   {
       newNode->next = list;
       return newNode;
   }
   m = list;
   while(m->next)
   {
       if(value < m->next->number)
           break;
       m = m->next;
   }
   newNode->next = m->next;
   m->next = newNode;
   return list;
}
```

Your main function should now iterate over reading the numbers for the different short lists as below. As you see, variable names are more explicit than yours. They are limited to the minimum and there are no global variables.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    NODE *globalList = NULL, *lists[100];
    int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val;

    printf("\n Enter the number of lists:");
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);
    if(nbrOfLists < 0 || nbrOfLists > 100)
        return -1;
    for(listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++) 
    {
        printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ",listNo+1);
        scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
        lists[listNo] = NULL;
        for(valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)
        {
            printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo+1);
            scanf("%d", &val);

            // Here we insert the value in both lists
            lists[listNo] = insertValue(lists[listNo], val);
            globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);
        }
        display(lists[listNo]);
    }
    display(globalList);
    return 0;
}
```

Your display function is correct. I provide it below, but it's the same as yours. The problem you encountered was because I forgot to initialize the fields of the node after I malloc it.

```
void display(NODE * list) 
{
    while(list) 
    {
        printf("%d ->", list->number);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. However, when I am using the display function I get infinite output. Please can you append your answer with display function as well. It will be great.

Comment: Here is the program that I compiled: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ku7a6i4isrcs0ut/chea.txt?dl=0

Comment: There is a mistake in the function insertValue. I didn't initialize newNode. I'm modifying the answer to fix this.